# Date Archive pages 404 error

Tags: archives, 404-error

I am building my own theme and realized that all date archive pages (all date, month and year) are throwing a 404 (its a locally hosted site). Its not theme specific as I thought earlier, because I thought its happening because of a custom post template I created. But when I changed the theme to twentythirteen (latest version), the same thing happened. My wordpress is also at its latest version and permalink settings are set to: http://domain.name/sample-post/

I will really appreciate your thoughts on this!

**UPDATE1:**
I changed to the default permalink structure and it works. Daily archive link now is: http://domain.name/?m=20140505 and its not giving a 404. BUT if I change back to the %postname% permalink structure

1. I installed URL Rewrite Module and did the mod_rewrite changes in web.config. still getting a 404
2. Then I added these rules to my .htaccess(I had to create it, as per wordpress codex instructions):

   #BEGIN WordPress
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    
    # END WordPress

   Still got a 404.
3. I am asked to remove write access on web.config file. So I did that by manually removing write access in the file's properties (right click a file->properties->permissions...). Still getting a 404!

here's my web.config now:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
 <conditions>
 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?page_id={R:0}" />
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

Please share if I am doing something wrong here. Will much appreciate your response!

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I am using wordpress version 3.9.1 for the site (locally hosted).

Comment: You have flushed your permalinks again to make sure that this isn't causing the problem